# Running powershell cmdlets throws Exceptions

Tags: c#, powershell, exception

I am trying to execute powershell scripts in C# using the codepiece below.
The cmdlet is actually being executed (opening google in browser). But there are several exceptions thrown, no matter what cmdlet i execute. How can i get rid of them?

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    var script = "Start-Process " + "\"" + "www.google.de" + "\"";
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(script);

    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

The exceptions thrown are:

> 'System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException'
>   'System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException'
>   'System.Management.Automation.DriveNotFoundException'

Comment: I just tested your `using` statement with a C# Windows Form. It worked without exception. With the information provided, it does not appear that this is what is causing your errors.

Comment: Which SDK file are you referencing? What version of powershell?

Comment: Why are you not using a direct call to start a program and instead invoke a PowerShell to run a program?

Answer (score 0):

I am referencing
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0`

When I run Visual Studio as admin, all the exception dont show up. Will my application have problems when running as standard user?